# Need to insert string into mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have such a table:

> ...| country | visa | remarks |..

"country" row is already prefilled, now i need to insert string like this:

> Afghanistan@Visa required@,
>
> Albania@Visa not required@90 days,
>
> Antigua and Barbuda@Visa not required@,
>
> Bangladesh@Visa on    arrival@30 days. Conditions apply.,

into the table.

Can anyone advice me the best way to do this?

Tnx a lot!

Comment: Of course string can be modified soever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split a string with the command

```
explode
```

If I understood your question right, you want sth. like this:

```
<?php
    $country = array(
        "Afghanistan@Visa required@",
        "Albania@Visa not required@90 days","Antigua and Barbuda@Visa not required@",
         "Bangladesh@Visa on arrival@30 days. Conditions apply."
    );

    foreach($country as $string){
        $data = explode("@",$string);

        mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE tbl_name SET visa = '" . $data[1] . "' WHERE country = '" . $data[0] . "'");
        mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE tbl_name SET remarks = '" . $data[2] . "' WHERE country = '" . $data[0] . "'");

    }

?>
```

by the way, these are really PHP basics.
Maybe you should try a tutorial like this one:

[w3schools PHP tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp)